# Какой первичный ключ лучше? id +user_id vs id

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование, индексы

Есть 2 таблицы. Таблица юзеров (user) и таблица их целей(goal_data). 
Чаще всего из таблицы целей будет выборка всех целей конкретного пользователя.

Стоит ли делать составной ключ в таблице goal_data ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или сделать индекс (id, user_id) ?

Меня смущает что если делать составной primary key, то id идет первым полем и будет ли смысл... Плохо знаю теорию b-деревьев.
Подскажите кто сталкивался на практике))

Comment: Выбор первичного ключа в принципе не связан с выполнением запросов. Он зависит только от логики отображаемого в БД процесса. *Чаще всего из таблицы целей будет выборка всех целей конкретного пользователя.* Достаточно индекса по пользователю.

Comment: Если `goal_data.id` - столбец с уникальными значениями, то , по-моему, нет особобого смысла использовать композитный первичный ключ длч этой таблицы... PS для `user_id` разумеется придется создать отлельный индекс